# There is no build provider registered for the extension '.jpg'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I approached a jpg image `www.demo.net/images/1.jpg`on my web site, it gave me the error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
There is no build provider registered for the extension '.jpg'. You can register one in the    <compilation><buildProviders> section in machine.config or web.config.
```

It is a asp.net mvc 4 site. It worked in localhost but failed on the hosted server.

So I modified it as

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <buildProviders>
    <remove extension=".jpg"/>
    <add extension=".jpg" type="System.Web.Compilation.WebHandlerBuildProvider"/>
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>
```

The image is not still shown and the error became wild.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request.        Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The page must have a <%@ webhandler class="MyNamespace.MyClass" ... %> directive.

Source Error:


Line 1:  ÿØÿàJFIFHHÿá
Line 2:  ExifMM*    †Œ1˜2žÿ‡i²ˆ%VêzêAppleiPhone 3GS4.3.52012:10:27 14:22:05‚šü‚ˆ"ˆ'P0221 ‘’4’<’’        ’
Line 3:  D’L’‘00’’00 0100   ¢ÿÿ¤è¤¤¤


Source File: /images/1.jpg    Line: 1

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18045
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hosed provider reset the IIS setting, then it was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

There's something wrong with the handler mappings in IIS. It's trying to actually *run* the jpg as if it was an aspx page, but has no build provider for a file type of jpg. That's fine. It *shouldn't* because jpgs aren't supposed to be built. Adding a build provider for it only served to freak the hell out of the compiler. IIS should simply treat a jpg as what it is, a static file, and serve it up. You need to determine why isn't doing that.

Comment: I have no control on IIS, should the hosted provider deal with that or I have to change my web.config?

Comment: This is typically handled in IIS, but Web.config has the potential to override. See: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap. This also may be interesting to you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/01/asp-net-4-0-enables-routing-of-extensionless-urls-without-impacting-static-requests.aspx.

Comment: I added one code <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpg" mimeType="image/jpg" />
      </staticContent> but it is still not working.